# iPhoto crashes on import

Tags: photos.app

Every time I import photos with iPhoto, it crashes!

1. I have no idea how to diagnose. I used cleanapp to remove all traces of iPhoto
2. I just purchased http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/ to try rebuilding and importing photos, but no luck
3. I have created and removed about 10 libraries, and still no luck
4. It's always creating folders called "iPhoto Library Recovered Photos"

Every time I try to import it just crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using iPhoto '11 9.2, you are not alone. The upgrade to [9.2.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1462) this week fixed this for me.

Comment: Where did you find that update?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1462